# How to programmatically place objects in an arc and rotate them?

Tags: unity

I have created an arc of circles from the inspector without any issues, but I need to create them programmatically. The image below shows what I'm looking for.

[image]

How can I get the positions at which to instantiate them, and how would I easily rotate them around the circle path, so that the arc ends up on the other side of the circle?

Comment: Is it me or this question looked quite different when I saw it at first.

Comment: @SuperHyperMegaSomething you can always look at the edit log

Answer (score 3):

Positioning those is fairly trivial once you're familiar with circle-math (or trigonometry):

```
int objectCount = 7;
float angle = 90.0f; // Initial angle.
float increment = 180.0f / objectCount;
float radius = <distance from center>;
for (int i = 0; i < objectCount; i++)
{
    // Make sure angle-units match up.
    float x = cos(angle) * radius;
    float y = sin(angle) * radius;

    Vector2 pos = new Vector2(x, y);
    // Instantiate with pos.

    angle -= increment;
}
```

We simply start with an angle, position the object correctly, and then increment the angle correctly. This solution works for any number of objects (well, depending on how you'd want those to be positioned).

For animating these, all you have to do is to update the initial angle value, so for an example, move the `angle` from 90 to 270. This could possibly also be done by rotating a parent object, whose children the balls are, without having to manually reposition the children, which you would have to do if you go with the angle-sliding approach.

Comment: When I used the code you provided I got [this](https://imgur.com/a/Z6Y9j). I tried changing the increment to 30.0f but that didn't get me the result I had in the in original image. Am I missing something? Also in my original question, the second part was about animating the rotation of the arc from its initial position over the circle to the other half (either anti/clockwise) using a coroutine over a duration. I preferably need to do this without creating a parent object for all the balls. `move the angle from 90 to 270` does not really give me a good idea as to how this would be done.

Comment: @Containment Check your objects, if you're creating them according to another object's orientation, then it's most likely that object's fault.