# Arrange UI images in half circle (180 degrees) in Unity

Tags: unity, unity-ui

Im basicly looking to create this image:
[image]

I have all these parts and black background as a separate image so the ideal thing would be to place them with border between them but I could also probably make parts with border. The thing is I would need to turn these images on and off base on input ( think of them a some kind of health bar). Also if there is any other way to do this pleas let me know like some custom fill or something. I could probably arrange them by hand but I think that is kind a hacky solution and it would take forever.

Example of a part:

[image]

I try using this code that I found on similar post:

```
 private void arrangeImages()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < imgParts.Length; i++)
    {
        float angle = i * Mathf.PI / imgParts.Length;
        Vector3 newPos = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius, Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius);

        imgParts[i].rectTransform.position = newPos;

    }
}
```

But the this is how it turns out:

[image]

Comment: Probably easiest to do that by code. Placing objects on a circle, rotation done by degree. There should be at least one example here already

Comment: Yeah I figure but I cant rely find a good example to place them with right spacing and orientation and I'm not rely good with math that is involved to write it my selfie.

Comment: https://blog.unity.com/technology/intro-to-2d-world-building-with-sprite-shape this might be another approach, using sprite shapes

Comment: But can you use sprite shapes in UI?

Comment: Have you considered using the UI Image Fill Method for this? This gives you a way to reveal pie slices of an image by dialing a Fill Amount parameter up and down — it's specifically made for making round health bars, progress bars, timers, etc.

Comment: I did the problem is that the picture is half circle not a full circle so the fil doesn't rely work.

Comment: Then make it a full circle and just use fill amounts between 0 and 0.5 no?

Comment: Just had that Idea myself will try it.

Comment: [This](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/150008/how-to-programmatically-place-objects-in-an-arc-and-rotate-them) has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 1):

Ended creating a full circle and just did normal radial fill to half value.
Here is a circle example:

[image]

And then I just fill it to specific value taking in consideration segments. Here is sample code I put together.

```
public static void FillHalfCircle(float value, int segments,Image fillImage)
    {
        if (value > segments)
            value = segments;

        float valueToFill = (0.5f/ segments) * value;

        fillImage.fillAmount = valueToFill;

    }
```